# Using Alecrim Core Data with Swift 3

Tags: swift, core-data, xcode8, alecrimcoredata

I'm having trouble with Alecrim Core Data in Xcode 8 Beta. The DataContext and DataContextOptions seem to be missing from the Swift_3 branch. Grasping at straws, I just updated the files from the master branch to Swift3 syntax hoping the functionality hadn't changed too much. But when it tries to read data I get an error message "Cannot fetch without an NSManagedObjectContext in scope".
I've done as much triage as I can think of. Breakpoints set at the spot that creates an NSManagedObjectContext and I can see it. The place that creates the fetchRequest has been updated with the new NSFetchReqeust syntax (although I see no sign of a MOC there).

Here's my link into the Alecrim lib DataContext:

```
let dataContext = DataContext()

extension DataContext
{
    public var collections: Table<CoreDataCollection> { return Table<CoreDataCollection>(context: self) }
    public var expressions: Table<CoreDataExpression> { return Table<CoreDataExpression>(context: self) }
    public var fileAssets: Table<CoreDataFileAsset> { return Table<CoreDataFileAsset>(context: self) }
    public var purchases: Table<CoreDataPurchase> { return Table<CoreDataPurchase>(context: self) }
    public var reeConfigs: Table<CoreDataReeConfig> { return Table<CoreDataReeConfig>(context: self) }
    public var stickers: Table<CoreDataSticker> { return Table<CoreDataSticker>(context: self) }

}
```

And the part that attempts to get data:

```
for item in dataContext.reeConfigs {
    let reeConfigVO = ReeConfigVO()
    reeConfigVO.initFromCoreData(item)
    items.append(reeConfigVO)
}
```

I'm not sure if this will be helpful but the part of Alecrim that's tossing the error:

```
// MARK: - GenericQueryable

extension TableProtocol {

    public final func execute() -> [Self.Element] {
        do {
            return try self.toFetchRequest().execute() as [Self.Element]
        }
        catch let error {
            AlecrimCoreDataError.handleError(error)
        }
    }

}

// MARK: - CoreDataQueryable

extension TableProtocol {

    public final func toFetchRequest<ResultType: NSFetchRequestResult>() -> NSFetchRequest<ResultType> {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<ResultType>()

        fetchRequest.entity = self.entityDescription

        fetchRequest.fetchOffset = self.offset
        fetchRequest.fetchLimit = self.limit
        fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = (self.limit > 0 && self.batchSize > self.limit ? 0 : self.batchSize)

        fetchRequest.predicate = self.predicate
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = self.sortDescriptors

        return fetchRequest
    }

}
```

Does anyone have experience with Alecrim in Swift 3 that can help figure out what's going wrong?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer I was looking for. I'm not sure this is what Alecrim wants to be done because, as I mentioned, the swift_3 branch doesn't even contain DataContext or DataContextOptions. However... if you have brought those files in from the main branch and updated them to swift 3 as I have and you have problems with the error "Cannot fetch without an MSManagedObjectContext in scope" here's how to fix it in the "TableProtocol.swift" file:

```
extension TableProtocol {

    public final func execute() -> [Self.Element] {
        do {
            return try self.context.fetch(self.toFetchRequest()) as! [Self.Element]
            //return try self.toFetchRequest().execute() as [Self.Element]
        }
        catch let error {
            AlecrimCoreDataError.handleError(error)
        }
    }
}
```

self.context is the NSManagedObjectContext (or a derived type i.e. our DataContext) that is needed for this to work. The as! [Self.Element] is crucial because Swift uses it to infer the RestultType in the function that builds the NSFetchRequest

Hope this helps.